# Syntax is wrong

Tags: python-3.x, class

I am using a method to return me value of deposit but it is showing syntax error.

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self,owner,balance):
        self.owner= owner
        self.balance= balance

    def deposit(self,amount_in):
         return self.balance+=amount_in
    def withdraw(self,amount_out):
        if amount_out>self.balance:
            print("Ther is not enough balance in your account")
        else:
            self.balance= self.balance- amount_out
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.owner) + ' ' + str(self.balance)
```

Error:

```
 File "<ipython-input-101-7e8824d5cebe>", line 7
    return self.balance+=amount_in
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to return an assignment.

Just change your code to this:

```
def deposit(self,amount_in):
    self.balance+=amount_in
```